# Bootstrap css overrules my slidemenu's css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've made my first slidemenu and everything seems fine except the 
 content in the menu itself. The slidemenu has pretty big spaces between each link and disabling the bootstrap stylesheet will make it looks like I want it to be.

Is there something i need to change in the Bootstrap.css?

[How i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXKj0.png)

[how it currently is with bootstrap.css active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohBrc.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:800');

body{
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: .9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: .7s;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    transition: .4s;
}

.nav .close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 22px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.slide a{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 36px;

}
#sidemenu{
    padding: 20px;
    transition: margin-left .7s;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--scripts-->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        function openSlideMenu() {
            document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '250px';
            document.getElementById('slidemenu').style.marginLeft= '250px';
        }
        function closeSlideMenu() {
            document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '0px';
            document.getElementById('slidemenu').style.marginLeft= '0px';
        }
    </script>

    <!--css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Index.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Frontpage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slidemenu">
                <span class="slide">
                    <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>
                </span>

                <div id="menu" class="nav">
                    <a href="#" class="close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </a>

                    <!--Links slidemenu-->
                    <a href="#">home</a>
                    <a href="#">about</a>
                    <a href="#">services</a>
                    <a href="#">portofolio</a>
                    <a href="#">contact</a>
                    <!--end of Links slidemenu-->
                </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="text1">
                    <p>x</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="text2">
                    <p>x</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="text3">
                    <p>x</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>


 Optional JavaScript 
 jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited a few of your css tags to reposition the navigation

Adding `width: 100%;` to `.nav a` fixed the navigation links.

Adding a `padding: 10px;` to `.slide a` opens up some space for your menu icon.

Finally adding `left: 130px;` to `.nav .close` will move the icon closer to the original position.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:800');

body{
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: .9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: .7s;
    display: block !important;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    transition: .4s;
}

.nav .close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 22px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 130px;
}

.slide a{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 10px;

}
#sidemenu{
    padding: 20px;
    transition: margin-left .7s;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}


.slide {
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--scripts-->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        function openSlideMenu() {
            document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '250px';
            document.getElementById('slidemenu').style.marginLeft= '250px';
        }
        function closeSlideMenu() {
            document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '0px';
            document.getElementById('slidemenu').style.marginLeft= '0px';
        }
    </script>

    <!--css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Index.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Frontpage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slidemenu">
                <span class="slide">
                    <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>
                </span>

                <div id="menu" class="nav">
                    <a href="#" class="close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </a>

                    <!--Links slidemenu-->
                    <a href="#">home</a>
                    <a href="#">about</a>
                    <a href="#">services</a>
                    <a href="#">portofolio</a>
                    <a href="#">contact</a>
                    <!--end of Links slidemenu-->
                </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="text1">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="text2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="text3">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed your nav from display flex to block this means you can customize the padding. The flex display was giving each element an equal height in the view.

Comment: thank you for looking into my code and making some corrections :) Is there perhaps a way to close the gaps betweens each <a href> so it will look like a compressed block?